# Adding PDFKit to XCode 4.6 project

Tags: xcode, pdf, frameworks

I like to add the PDFKit framework to one on my OS X Cocoa projects but if I try to add it in *Targets -> Summary -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries* it is not there. In addition, importing it in my .h file is not successful or better to say it is not found by auto complete. What can I do?

Thanks for your help!

SOLVED! See comments!

Comment: Ok, obviously I had to import the Quartz framework. Now it works. Maybe this little self help here will help some others to find out :)

Comment: You should add that as an answer to your question - it helped me.

Comment: What made it so obvious? I only found this thread as working solution... Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As asked for in the comments:

Ok, obviously I had to **import the Quartz framework**. Now it works. Maybe this little self help here will help some others to find out :)